# Which iOS versions are affected by the 2nd December date bug?

Tags: iphone, ios, bug

There is a date bug on iOS 11.1.2 which causes iOS to constantly respring after 2nd December, caused by recurring local notifications. [iPhone with repeating loading spinner](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/307584/37797)

I'm currently on iOS 11.0.1 and unaffected by this bug. **Which versions of iOS are affected?**

The [Apple support article](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208332) about the bug does not state which versions of iOS are affected, only that iOS 11.2 resolves the problem.

I was backing up my device ready to update to 11.1 as I haven't seen any reports of this version being affected, then watched as Apple stopped signing it right before my eyes. I don't want to update to iOS 11.2 for the potential of a jailbreak. Is 11.1.1 (the only other non-11.2 version being signed right now) susceptible to this bug?

Answer (score 2):

iOS (11.1.1 & 11.1.2) version are affected.

This bug fixed in iOS 11.2

Article link : https://appleinsider.com/articles/17/12/02/new-ios-bug-causes-some-devices-to-crash-on-dec-2-heres-how-to-fix-it

Comment: The article says the issue affects ‘the latest versions of iOS, including iOS 11.1.1 and 11.1.2’, not limiting it to those two versions.